# JWT token authentication websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, jwt

I am trying to make a WebSocket server authentication where after a successful login a JWT token is generated and passed to the client.

But I am confused how should client pass that token to the server for authentication.

I have seen many examples where people passing there token through the URL like this `const ws = new WebSocket("wss://somedomain.com?token=<token>");`   but is this secure?

or if you have any other authentication mechanism better than this then please help me.

Comment: jwt is **only** secure over ssl, like in your example

Comment: is there any other method? @LawrenceCherone